# Division by zero in numpy (sub)arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, divide-by-zero

I have three arrays that are processed with a mathematical function to get a final result array. Some of the arrays contain NaNs and some contain 0. However a division by zero logically raise a Warning, a calculation with NaN gives NaN. So I'd like to do certain operations on certain parts of the arrays where zeros are involved:

```
r=numpy.array([3,3,3])
k=numpy.array([numpy.nan,0,numpy.nan])
n=numpy.array([numpy.nan,0,0])
1.0*n*numpy.exp(r*(1-(n/k)))
```

e.g. in cases where k == 0, I'd like to get as a result 0. In all other cases I'd to calculate the function above. So what is the way to do such calculations on parts of the array (via indexing) to get a final single result array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy
r=numpy.array([3,3,3])
k=numpy.array([numpy.nan,0,numpy.nan])
n=numpy.array([numpy.nan,0,0])
indxZeros=numpy.where(k==0)
indxNonZeros=numpy.where(k!=0)
d=numpy.empty(k.shape)
d[indxZeros]=0
d[indxNonZeros]=n[indxNonZeros]/k[indxNonZeros]
print d
```

Comment: Please use the _edit_ button to add this as an edit to your original answer.

Comment: instead of using `np.where` to compute numerical indexing arrays, it is typically faster to use boolean indexing, i.e. doing `indxZeros = k == 0; indxNonZeros = ~idxZeros` will also work, probably faster.

Comment: Thanks tobias_k, I am still pretty new to answering questions on here.. I usually just browse for already asked questions for answers to my problems.. thanks for the suggestion I will keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 2):

Is following what you need?

```
>>> rv = 1.0*n*numpy.exp(r*(1-(n/k)))
>>> rv[k==0] = 0
>>> rv
array([ nan,   0.,  nan])
```

Comment: Basically yes, however this approach with processing first all at once and "cleaning" afterwards still raises the warning. I also would like to avoid the warning, so e.g. exluding the cases k==0 already before

Answer (score 1):

So, you may think that the solution to this problem is to use `numpy.where`, but the following:

```
numpy.where(k==0, 0, 1.0*n*numpy.exp(r*(1-(n/k))))
```

still gives a warning, as the expression is actually evaluated for the cases where k is zero, even if those results aren't used.

If this really bothers you, you can use `numexpr` for this expression, which will actually branch on the where statement and not evaluate the `k==0` case:

```
import numexpr
numexpr.evaluate('where(k==0, 0, 1.0*n*exp(r*(1-(n/k))))')
```

Another way, based on indexing as you asked for, involves a little loss in legibility

```
result = numpy.zeros_like(k)
good = k != 0
result[good] = 1.0*n[good]*numpy.exp(r[good]*(1-(n[good]/k[good])))
```

This can be bypassed somewhat by defining a `gaussian` function:

```
def gaussian(r, k, n):
    return 1.0*n*numpy.exp(r*(1-(n/k)))

result = numpy.zeros_like(k)
good = k != 0
result[good] = gaussian(r[good], k[good], n[good])
```